# Should I be using WebDriverFacade or WebDriver or PageObject?

Tags: serenity-bdd

What is the difference between using WebDriverFacade as opposed to Page Objects. I searched a lot and just can't seem to understand or find the answers. I am declaring WebDriverFacade for all my elements and do get the added functionality of waits, etc added before action happens on the element, which is good, but then what does Page object do differently other than getdriver()? Which one should I be using?

Comment: Page Object is a design approach while WebDriverFacade is a library which implements a webdriver wrapper.

Comment: Please add more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are two different [design patterns](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns).

A [Facade](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/facade) is meant to make the interface to a library or set of objects simpler. It wraps in simpler methods complex behavior or "outdated" style of programming, thus making the overall style of your project cleaner, even if you have to rely on some nasty ugly dependencies.

[image]

It does not have anything to do with your business logic.

A [Page Object](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) on the other hand is connected to your business logic. It will implement ways of interacting with a UI element, exposing behavior-like methods such as *completeOrder* and *performLogin*.

[image]

Most probably you will use both the *WebDriverFacade* and *Page Objects*, injecting the former into the latter, so that you will be able to implement the behavior methods.

```
class HomePage {
  
   HomePage(WebDriverFacade driver)() { this.driver = driver; }
   fun doStuff() { driver.getElement(blablabla).click(); }

}
```

Comment: I don't think I am still clear about the difference. Also if I am using WebDriverFacade can I use WebDriverListener to log events? If yes how?

Comment: The main difference is that a Facade is a gateway for more complex object interaction. In the context we are, it doesn't describe the SUT, but helps to deal with a more complex API (In this case, the WebDriver API). A Page Object describes your SUT, it has business logic, not acting simply as a gateway to other objects.

Comment: WebDriverListener would be a different question. I suggest reading this article https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-event-listener-example In here you can see how you register a WebDriverListener in an EventFiringWebDriver.

Comment: Thank you for your response João.

Comment: Regarding webdriverListener I know how to use it while just using selenium but am not sure how to use it in the context of webdriverfacade

Comment: I would suggest opening another question more focused on WebDriverListener. If the answer regarding WebDriverFacade and Page Objects was satisfactory, could you mark it as accepted, so other people will not answer it?